# Apostrophes in title attribute are HTML encoded in response

Tags: youtube-data-api

```
"snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2012-08-24T17:06:35.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCh6C5LG14uZKmwCgGxf-nDQ",
    "title": "Céline Dion - I&#39;m Alive (Official Video)",
    "description": "Celine Dion - I'm Alive (Official Video) Listen on Spotify: http://smarturl.it/Celine_Spotify_EN Listen on Apple Music: http://smarturl.it/Celine_AM_EN Amazon: ...",
    "thumbnails": {},
}
```

Any Idea why this is happening? It's well decoded into the `description` but not the `title` field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been a known issue of the API for quite some time.

Other users experienced it -- including myself. Yet, no documenting explanation and/or solution from Google emerged (as far as I know), neither here on SO, nor on Google's own issue tracker [site](https://issuetracker.google.com).

I myself am filtering the texts received from API endpoints through my own [HTML entity decoder](https://github.com/stvar/html-cref).

I recommend you do the same kind of cleaning-up, using tools available from the surrounding programming environment.

As a final note, interestingly enough, on my site [your video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NJsa6-y4sDs) does not produce HTML entities in the JSON text obtained from the API.