# YouTube videos API snippet title contains special characters in Next.js

Tags: javascript, next.js, youtube-data-api

I want to get the right video snippet title that doesn't include special characters.
I am using the API:

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search`,

with the part `snippet`.

Currently, I am getting the `snippet.title` below:

> `I&#39;M GONNA CARRY HER!!! Fortnite With Karina!`

I expected this title instead:

> I'm gonna carry her!!! Fortnite With Karina!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796718/html-entity-decode

Comment: I don't want to use jQuery

Comment: Pure javascript can be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, please acknowledge that what you've got from the API are not (quote from you) *special characters.*

To be technically precise, those sequence of characters are [HTML character references](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#character-references), also known as [HTML entities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references).

The behavior you've encountered is a [well-known issue of the API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59407159/8327971), for which there's no other solution that I know of, except that you yourself have to substitute those HTML entities for the actual characters that they stand for.

Now, I recommend against an *ad hoc solution*; that is I do recommend you to employ well-written well-tested well-known libraries that derive their non-trivial solution from carefully implemented code conforming to the current HTML standard.

In my opinion, [Mathias Bynens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/96656/mathias-bynens)' library is evidently a tool that meets each of the criteria I mentioned above:

> ## [he](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/he) [image: Build status] [image: Code coverage status]
>
> *he* (for “HTML entities”) is a robust HTML entity encoder/decoder written in JavaScript. It supports [all standardized named character references as per HTML](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#named-character-references), handles [ambiguous ampersands](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/ambiguous-ampersands) and other edge cases [just like a browser would](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#tokenizing-character-references), has an extensive test suite, and — contrary to many other JavaScript solutions — *he* handles astral Unicode symbols just fine. [An online demo is available.](https://mothereff.in/html-entities)

Answer (score 4):

I'm using [escape-goat](https://github.com/sindresorhus/escape-goat) as it operates as either a standalone function or as a [tagged template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_template_literals), depending on your use case:

```
const {htmlUnescape} = require('escape-goat');

htmlUnescape("I&#39;M GONNA CARRY HER!!! Fortnite With Karina!");
//=> 'I'm gonna carry her!!! Fortnite With Karina!'

htmlUnescape`Title: ${"I&#39;M GONNA CARRY HER!!! Fortnite With Karina!"}`;
//=> 'Title: I'm gonna carry her!!! Fortnite With Karina!'
```

When dealing with html encode/decode, always be wary of potential [XSS exploitation](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#Why_Can.27t_I_Just_HTML_Entity_Encode_Untrusted_Data.3F).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use raw JS and not import a library, I saw something in my travels that works for the simple use case you presented. It basically is stripping out the separators to get at the integer that represents a Unicode-16 character. `fromCharCode` looks up that integer and returns the character that matches the integer you give it.

```
const unescape = (str) => {
  return str.replace(/&#(\d+);/g, (match, dec) => String.fromCharCode(dec))
}
```

As Matt Hosch mentioned in his answer, you'd want to sanitize any data you receive to prevent an XSS.