# How to convert API fetched data containing '&#39;' or '&amp;' or '&quot;', to their human-readable value in nodeJs?

Tags: node.js, express, axios, youtube-data-api

Upon making API calls, I'm returned with following values, for example:

- Niall Horan - &quot;Slow Hands&quot; (Sophia Scott Cover)
- SLOW HANDS - Niall Horan | KINA GRANNIS &amp; KHS COVER
- Bruno Mars - That&#39;s What I Like (from the 2017 Brit Awards) (Official Live Performance)

Notice the ASCII codes here, or so I am assuming.

**How to convert these string to human-readable strings?**

This is how I'm making API calls:

```js
async function ytAxiosGetFunc(queryOfYtAxiosGetFunc, maxResultsOfYtAxiosGetFunc) {

  let ytExtractedResult = [];
  let ytVideoId = [];
  let ytVideoThumb = [];
  let ytVideoTitle = [];
  let ytVideoChannel = [];
  urlOfYtAxiosGetFunc = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=" + keys.google.apiKey[1] + "&part=snippet&order=relevance&type=video&videoEmbeddable=true";

  try {
    let ytResponse = await axios({
      url: urlOfYtAxiosGetFunc,
      method: "get",
      params: {
        q: queryOfYtAxiosGetFunc,
        maxResults: maxResultsOfYtAxiosGetFunc
      }
    })

    let ytResult = ytResponse.data;

    for (i = 0; i < (ytResult.items).length; i++) {
      ytVideoId[i] = ytResult.items[i].id.videoId;
      ytVideoThumb[i] = ytResult.items[i].snippet.thumbnails.default.url;
      ytVideoTitle[i] = unescape(ytResult.items[i].snippet.title);
      ytVideoChannel[i] = decodeURI(ytResult.items[i].snippet.channelTitle);
    }

    return {
      id: ytVideoId,
      thumb: ytVideoThumb,
      title: ytVideoTitle,
      channel: ytVideoChannel
    };
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```

Using `decodeURI`, `decodeURIComponent` and `unescape` did not help. Please suggest.

Comment: This is the answer to your question: [YouTube videos API snippet title contains special characters in Next.js](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66354130/8327971).

Comment: That is exactly what my query is. I'll go through it.

Comment: @stvar Literally, bruh. Thank you so much for looking this up. I was searching for exactly this, the past hour.

Comment: What can I say, @Varun (as the one answering that question): vote that up if it solved your issue.

Comment: @stvar Oh, I didn't realise that's you. Your answer deserves the upvote. :)

Answer (score -2):

As suggested by [@stvar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8327971/stvar).

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66354130/14597561 answers this question.

It worked for me as follows:

```js
npm install he
```

```js
const he = require("he");
```

```js
ytVideoTitle[i] = he.decode(ytResult.items[i].snippet.title);
ytVideoChannel[i] = he.decode(ytResult.items[i].snippet.channelTitle);
```